# React mouseEnter event not working when on mapped children

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just want these child elements to show a remove button on mouseover...

console logging in handleMouseEnter shows that on render, ALL children fire the mouseEnter event. it seems stuck in a loop. debugging is next to impossible.

problems only arise when onMouseEnter and onMouseLeave are left in the code.

```
render(){

    const handleMouseEnter = (tool) => this.setState({display : tool});
    const handleMouseLeave = () => this.setState({display : "none"});

return (
 <div>

    <div className="search-result-background">
      <div className="search-result-row row">
        <div className="col-md-4">
        </div>
        <div className="col-md-4">
        <form>
      <TextFieldGroup className="find-tool-search-bar"
        onChange= {this.checkToolExists}
        value = {this.state.toolname}
        field = 'toolname'
        label = ''
        error = {this.state.errors}
        placeholder = "FIND IN FAVORITES"
      />
    </form>
       </div>

<div className="col-md-4">
        <ButtonToolbar>
          <DropdownButton noCaret onSelect={this.sort} bsSize="large" title="Sort by" id="dropdown-size-large">
            <MenuItem eventKey="1">Name</MenuItem>
            <MenuItem eventKey="2">Uploaded Date</MenuItem>
          </DropdownButton>
        </ButtonToolbar>
        </div>
        <h1 className="search-error">{this.state.errors}</h1>
        <div className="col-md-12" >
          {this.state.filteredTools.map((tool,i)=>
            <div key ={i} className={"child " + tool.toolname } onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter(tool.toolname)}
            onMouseLeave={handleMouseLeave}> {this.state.display == tool.toolname ?
               <button >remove?</button> : null}
              <Link to={`/tools/${tool.id.substring(4)}`}>

              <Thumbnail 
                         className="thumb" src={logoImagePurple} alt="242x200">
                <h3>{tool.toolname}</h3>
              </Thumbnail>
              </Link>
            </div> 
          )}
        </div>
      </div> 
    </div>
  </div>          
)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem is this line:

`onMouseEnter={handleMouseEnter(tool.toolname)}`

You should change it to:

`onMouseEnter={() => handleMouseEnter(tool.toolname)}`